# Pandas duplicate rows replacing one column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe *train_df* that looks like this (this is an example, I have a lot more rows):

```
term               text_snippet        abbr   label
Operatiekamer      De OK is open       OK      1
```

I have another dataframe *abbr_df* that looks like this:

```
abbr    term
OK      Operatiekamer
OK      Operatiekledij
```

What I want to achieve is that my *train_df* is supplemented with the same text snippet and abbr as above but with the wrong term and label 0. Such as:

```
term               text_snippet        abbr   label
Operatiekamer      De OK is open       OK      1
Operatiekledij     De OK is open       OK      0
```

I feel like there is a sophisticated method to achieve this but I just can't get it to work. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: how would you know how to fill the text_snippet? here in the example it is easy, but if you have several of them in your real data, is abbr the common values to define the text_snippet?

Comment: @Ben.T Well for each abbr text_snippet pair (idk if this makes sense) I'd have to make the combination with the right and wrong terms go into the dataframe. Idk if I understand your question well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a similar approach as the previous answer in terms of merging but with a different handling of the columns:

```
import pandas as pd
train_df=pd.DataFrame({"term":['Operatiekamer'], "text_snippet":['De OK is open'], "abbr":['OK'],"label":[1]})             
abbr_df=pd.DataFrame({"abbr":['OK','OK'],"term":['Operatiekamer','Operatiekledij']})

train_df=abbr_df.merge(train_df,on=['abbr'],how='inner',suffixes=[None,"_train"])

train_df.loc[train_df.term != train_df.term_train,"label"] = 0
train_df.drop(columns=["term_train"],inplace=True)
train_df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.merge` to populate `abbr_df` with the matching values of `train_df`. Of course the labels will not be populated correctly, but you can use `apply` to set the labels to `0` if the `terms` of the two dataframes do not match:

```
import pandas as pd

train_df_data = [{'term': 'Operatiekamer', 'text_snippet': 'De OK is open', 'abbr': 'OK', 'label': 1}]
abbr_df_data = [ { "abbr": "OK", "term": "Operatiekamer" }, { "abbr": "OK", "term": "Operatiekledij" } ]
train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_df_data)
abbr_df = pd.DataFrame(abbr_df_data)

df = pd.merge(train_df, abbr_df, on='abbr') # merge dataframes on abbr
df['label'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.term_x==x.term_y else 0, axis=1) # set labels
df = df.drop(columns=['term_x']).rename(columns={'term_y': 'term'}) #remove redundant column
```

result:

|  | text_snippet | abbr | label | term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | De OK is open | OK | 1 | Operatiekamer |
| 1 | De OK is open | OK | 0 | Operatiekledij |

Comment: Nice, to create label, it would be more efficient to do in vectorize way like `df['label'] = df['term_x'].eq(df['term_y']).astype(int)` :)